# No such file or directory with subprocess.Popen, not caused by string command

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm running a webservice which operates on wav-files, but I don't want to allow just any upload, so I check the duration of the uploaded file first with the following code:

```
os.chdir("/home/me/bin")
proc = subprocess.Popen(['duration',wav],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE,shell=False)
out, errors = proc.communicate()
time = int(float(out.strip()))
if time > MAX_TIME:
    sys.exit(1)
```

This has been working fine for several months, but recently (after a migration, I should add) I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/webservice.py", line 100, in <module>
    proc = subprocess.Popen(['duration',wav],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE,shell=False)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 639, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1228, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

This error seems to be mostly caused by the use of a string for the command instead of a list, but that's not the case here. When I try to reproduce this error in a separate script, I can't.

Anyone have any idea what might be the cause here?

Comment: did you manually verify that `duration` is a cmd, or a file that can be executed in the specified folder

Comment: After the migration, did you check the PATH environment variable?  It can be different for a web server. Where is `duration`?

Comment: Yes, that's what I do when trying to reproduce the error. Now I have found that adding "./" might solve the problem, although I don't understand why, since "." is in my path...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Commands without a path are always *only* looked up on the `PATH`. You cannot cd to a directory and have `subprocess` (or your shell for that matter) find a command located in that  directory without specifying at least a relative path. This is standard command lookup behaviour.

If you want to run a command in the current working directory, you *must* specify a path of `./` to make it explicit the `PATH` search semantics are not to be used.

Relative paths in the `PATH` environment variable are also not supported everywhere; adding `.` to PATH is considered a security risk and some systems explicitly filter out `.` from the PATH. You must have migrated away from a system that allowed this, to a system that does disallow `.` in the `PATH`.

Comment: The path seems to be changed completely during webservice execution. When I ssh to the server and echo $PATH everything is fine. When I print it during execution it only contains "/usr/bin:/bin". I don't know why yet, but anyway this is probably not relevant to this thread.

Comment: @niefpaarschoenen: The env variable can be set by just about anything involved in the running of your web service. The environment the server is run in, the server itself, the python code in the web service, etc. all can alter the environment.

Comment: @niefpaarschoenen: In any case, avoid using `.` on the `PATH` and use `./command` instead, or better still use absolute paths. That is always better from a security point of view.

Comment: For those curious: the main reason was not running a cron job in a login shell.

Answer (score 0):

The error might not be pertaining to the executable you're feeding to Popen, but to an another executable that is subsequently called and is not found in the PATH of the new environment.

This exact situation happened to me, and the problem was that I had not installed the interpreter for the script I was calling. Frustrating to debug because the error message does not tell you which file it could not find.

Answer (score -2):

Consider doing something like the following at the top of you file then there should be no need to `chdir` unless you have to for another reason.

```
import os
cmd = os.path.expanduser('~/bin/duration')
if not os.path.isfile(cmd):
    raise IOError("command '%s' not found" % cmd)


proc = subprocess.Popen([cmd,wav ...
```

Comment: Sounds like you're assuming everything runs off of the home directory, why?

Comment: The OP was trying to run a script `/home/me/bin/duration` the point I was trying to make was that one shouldn't have to `os.chdir` just to be in the right directory to run their script. In principle one should be able to run a script from any location and it do the right thing. Likewise I don't like the idea of having to tweak the PATH just to get a script to work.